# Find value of f(z) = sin^2(z) at z=i

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the value of the function $f(z) = sin^2(z)$ at $z_0 = i$. Express your answer in the form $a + ib$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin^2(i) = i\sinh(1)\cdot i\sinh(1) = -\sinh^2(1)$$
Which is entirely real